# How can I access result counts of google custom search in python?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-custom-search

I used googleapiclient in python to retrieve search results from around 30 websites for a keyword. However,I'm having trouble reading results. It seems that there is a key to see the number of total results, but not for search results for each site?

First, I used the following to get the results:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey='mykeyhere')

queries = "thewordiamlookingfor"
res = service.cse().list(q= queries, cx='idhere',).execute()
```

in res:

```
res.keys()
[u'kind', u'url', u'items', u'context', u'queries', u'searchInformation']

res[u'searchInformation']
{u'formattedSearchTime': u'0.73', u'formattedTotalResults': u'19,700,000', u'totalResults': u'19700000', u'searchTime': 0.72519}
```

The 'total number of results is 19700000, but how can I access result counts for each site search? I don't think there is a way to access the count, according to the 'items' tag?

```
res[u'items'][0].keys()
[u'kind', u'title', u'displayLink', u'htmlTitle', u'formattedUrl', u'htmlFormattedUrl', u'pagemap', u'snippet', u'htmlSnippet', u'link']
```